# MVC - Mixed Auth - OWIN + Windows Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, windows-authentication

I need to have both windows authentication and owin (forms) authentication but i can't get it to work.

Probably the best option is to have two sites that have different authentication methods.

I found a project that does what i want: [MVC5-MixedAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth). But it uses IISExpress and i can't get it to work with Local IIS.

The error that occurs is:

> Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.

If i remove all my *ConfigureAuth()* method inside *Startup.Auth.cs* it doesn't throw the error but i can't login because it is needed to do *CookieAuthentication*.

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(dbEmployeePortal.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, UserMaster, int>
            (
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                    getUserIdCallback: (id) => (Int32.Parse(id.GetUserId()))
            )
        }
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
}
```

Any idea?

**UPDATE 1**

The error

> Request filtering is configured on the Web server to deny the request because the query string is too long.

appears because occurs a login loop when it tries to reach the login page.

Comment: That error is almost always due to an infinite redirection caused by requiring auth on the login page. In other words, user needs to login so they're redirect to the login page with a return url in the querystring. However, the login page itself requires the user to be logged in, so they're redirected to the login page (with an even longer return url in the querystring). Rinse and repeat until the query string blows up. Make sure that you're allowing anonymous access to anything that runs on your login page (child actions and such included).

Comment: Hey @ChrisPratt, yes i agree with you it occurs due to an infinite redirection loop.

The problem is that i don't want Anonymous Access.
I want to get the UserId from Window Auth and then search for any user with that Id and signin him.

If i allow anonymous authentication, the user that appears is NT AUTHORITY\...

Comment: Well, again, the only reason that would occur is if there's something about your login page, itself, that requires a user to already be authorized. In that respect it probably has nothing at all to do with the fact that you're using mixed auth. Disabling it merely disables the authorization check, and allows the login page to load anonymously. You just need to figure out what it is requiring authorizing during the load of that action.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, Ok i already search for it but i'm going to "dig" again

Comment: Oh. Well, that's your problem. And it's kind of pointless anyways. If you were to get any info from Windows Auth, the user is already signed in. If you're going to mix auth, it's still an either or thing.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, so i can't get the current user inside a domain and login with his account automatically?

Am i thinking wrongly?

Comment: They're *already* logged in.

Comment: I see... so i just need to return the correct Id though the UserId that WindowIdentity gives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resolved!

I followed the example: [MVC5-MixAuth](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth)

Credits: [Mohammed Younes](https://github.com/MohammadYounes)

**UPDATE 1**

**Problem:** I needed to have both *Anonymous Authentication* and *Windows Authentication* enabled. 
But when you enable them both, you can only get *NT AUTHORITY\IUSR*.

**Resolution:** To get the current user (introduced with NTLM prompt), we need to create an handler that will execute when an user enter at login page.
When the user hits the login page, the handler will get the current windows identity cached in the browser and then set as the *LogonUserIdentity*.

**Note:** I needed to use *windows first* login, when the user hits the login page it will try to get the correspondent ASP.NET User.

**Handler**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace MixedAuth
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Managed handler for windows authentication.
    /// </summary>
    public class WindowsLoginHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public HttpContext Context { get; set; }
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            this.Context = context;

            //if user is already authenticated, LogonUserIdentity will be holding the current application pool identity.
            //to overcome this:
            //1. save userId to session.
            //2. log user off.
            //3. request challenge.
            //4. log user in.

            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                this.SaveUserIdToSession(context.User.Identity.GetUserId());

                await WinLogoffAsync(context);

                context.RequestChallenge();
            }
            else if (!context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.RequestChallenge();
            }
            else
            {
                // true: user is trying to link windows login to an existing account
                if (this.SessionHasUserId())
                {
                    var userId = this.ReadUserIdFromSession();
                    this.SaveUserIdToContext(userId);
                    await WinLinkLoginAsync(context);
                }
                else // normal login.
                    await WinLoginAsync(context);
            }
        }

        #region helpers
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes Windows login action against account controller.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task WinLoginAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var routeData = this.CreateRouteData(Action.Login);

            routeData.Values.Add("returnUrl", context.Request["returnUrl"]);
            routeData.Values.Add("userName", context.Request.Form["UserName"]);

            await ExecuteController(context, routeData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute Link Windows login action against account controller.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task WinLinkLoginAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var routeData = this.CreateRouteData(Action.Link);

            await ExecuteController(context, routeData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes Windows logoff action against controller.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task WinLogoffAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            var routeData = this.CreateRouteData(Action.Logoff);

            await ExecuteController(context, routeData);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes controller based on route data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="routeData"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private async Task ExecuteController(HttpContext context, RouteData routeData)
        {
            var wrapper = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
            MvcHandler handler = new MvcHandler(new RequestContext(wrapper, routeData));

            IHttpAsyncHandler asyncHandler = ((IHttpAsyncHandler)handler);
            await Task.Factory.FromAsync(asyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest, asyncHandler.EndProcessRequest, context, null);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Extensions**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MixedAuth
{
    public enum Action { Login, Link, Logoff };

    public static class MixedAuthExtensions
    {
        const string userIdKey = "windows.userId";
        //http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
        const int fakeStatusCode = 418;

        const string controllerName = "Account";
        const string loginActionName = "WindowsLogin";
        const string linkActionName = "LinkWindowsLogin";
        const string logoffActionName = "WindowsLogoff";
        const string windowsLoginRouteName = "Windows/Login";


        public static void RegisterWindowsAuthentication(this MvcApplication app)
        {
            app.EndRequest += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                HttpContext.Current.ApplyChallenge();
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers ignore route for the managed handler.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="routes"></param>
        public static void IgnoreWindowsLoginRoute(this RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute(windowsLoginRouteName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// By pass all middleware and modules, by setting a fake status code.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public static void RequestChallenge(this HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = fakeStatusCode;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoke on end response only. Replaces the current response status code with 401.2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public static void ApplyChallenge(this HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == fakeStatusCode)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                context.Response.SubStatusCode = 2;

                //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx
                //context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handler"></param>
        /// <param name="action"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static RouteData CreateRouteData(this WindowsLoginHandler handler, Action action)
        {
            RouteData routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.RouteHandler = new MvcRouteHandler();

            switch (action)
            {
                case Action.Login:
                    routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", loginActionName);
                    break;
                case Action.Link:
                    routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", linkActionName);
                    break;
                case Action.Logoff:
                    routeData.Values.Add("controller", controllerName);
                    routeData.Values.Add("action", logoffActionName);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("unknonw action value '{0}'.", action));
            }
            return routeData;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Saves userId to the items collection inside <see cref="HttpContext"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SaveUserIdToContext(this WindowsLoginHandler handler, string userId)
        {
            if (handler.Context.Items.Contains(userIdKey))
                throw new ApplicationException("Id already exists in context.");

            handler.Context.Items.Add("windows.userId", userId);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads userId from item collection inside <see cref="HttpContext"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>The item will removed before this method returns</remarks>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static int ReadUserId(this HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (!context.Items.Contains(userIdKey))
                throw new ApplicationException("Id not found in context.");

            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(context.Items[userIdKey] as string);
            context.Items.Remove(userIdKey);

            return userId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the session contains an entry for userId.
        /// </summary>
        public static bool SessionHasUserId(this WindowsLoginHandler handler)
        {
            return handler.Context.Session[userIdKey] != null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Save a session-state value with the specified userId.
        /// </summary>
        public static void SaveUserIdToSession(this WindowsLoginHandler handler, string userId)
        {
            if (handler.SessionHasUserId())
                throw new ApplicationException("Id already exists in session.");

            handler.Context.Session[userIdKey] = userId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reads userId value from session-state.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>The session-state value removed before this method returns.</remarks>
        /// <param name="session"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ReadUserIdFromSession(this WindowsLoginHandler handler)
        {
            string userId = handler.Context.Session[userIdKey] as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userIdKey))
                throw new ApplicationException("Id not found in session.");

            handler.Context.Session.Remove(userIdKey);

            return userId;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a form for windows login, simulating external login providers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
        /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static MvcForm BeginWindowsAuthForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return htmlHelper.BeginForm("Login", "Windows", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a form for windows login, simulating external login providers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="htmlHelper"></param>
        /// <param name="htmlAttributes"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static MvcForm BeginWindowsAuthForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return htmlHelper.BeginForm("Login", "Windows", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
        }



    }
}
```

**Note**
You need to have AccountController.cs as partial.

**AccountController.Windows.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using MixedAuth;

namespace EmployeePortal.Web.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public partial class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        //
        // POST: /Account/WindowsLogin
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult WindowsLogin(string userName, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            var loginInfo = GetWindowsLoginInfo();

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var user = UserManager.Find(loginInfo);
            if (user != null)
            {
                SignIn(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", returnUrl = returnUrl }));
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/WindowsLogOff
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public void WindowsLogOff()
        {
            AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Account/LinkWindowsLogin
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> LinkWindowsLogin()
        {
            int userId = HttpContext.ReadUserId();

            //didn't get here through handler
            if (userId <= 0)
                return RedirectToAction("Login");

            HttpContext.Items.Remove("windows.userId");

            //not authenticated.
            var loginInfo = GetWindowsLoginInfo();
            if (loginInfo == null)
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");

            //add linked login
            var result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(userId, loginInfo);

            //sign the user back in.
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user != null)
                await SignInAsync(user, false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
                return RedirectToAction("Manage");

            return RedirectToAction("Manage", new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }

        #region helpers
        private UserLoginInfo GetWindowsLoginInfo()
        {
            if (!Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;

            return new UserLoginInfo("Windows", Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.ToString());
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class WindowsLoginConfirmationViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then, you need to add the handler:

```
<add name="Windows Login Handler" path="Login" verb="GET,POST" type="MixedAuth.WindowsLoginHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

**Startup.cs**

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(dbEmployeePortal.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);


PathString path = new PathString("/Account/Login");
if (GlobalExtensions.WindowsAuthActive)
    path = new PathString("/Windows/Login");

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    //LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
    LoginPath = path
});
// Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

Then you need to configure **Local IIS** to use *WindowsAuthentication* and *AnonymousAuthentication*. You can do this in the Authentication Module.

**Note** If you don't have *WindowsAuthentication* go to *Control Panel* then *Programs and Features* then "Turn Windows features on or off":

> select "Internet Information Services" > "World Wide Web" > "Security"
>   and select Windows Authentication.

Comment: What is the code for GetUserId? (I assume it is an extension method.)

Comment: Hey @MatthewRodatus, it's an extension from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`

Comment: You can the another branch of the Mohammed Younes: OWIN-MixedAuth. This one you don't need to do all this code by yourself.

https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth

Comment: And why shouldn't it be considered a solution? It works, doesn't have a big performance impact and you have the code on your side and you can change it whenever you want to accommodate your needs...

Comment: And... a third of the code that I showed, it's about the controllers in your application, which already exist and you only have to edit some parts

Comment: Thanks, @LeandroSoares! What is `GlobalExtensions.WindowsAuthActive`? Couldn't find it anywhere in the code.

Comment: Hey, @Alex. That's just a `boolean` to enable or disable all this code.

Comment: Thanks, @LeandroSoares! I'm using the OWIN MixedAuth library and your code here to do this: https://github.com/MohammadYounes/OWIN-MixedAuth/issues/64 Any thoughts?

Comment: Well I'm not using that library only this code provided by Mohammed Younes. You need to change the action `WindowsLogin` to what suits the best on your case. In my case I try to find the user with the SID, just change that.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks, @LeandroSoares :)

Comment: @LeandroSoares, what's been your experience with the OWIN-MixedAuth as far as security? Some people discourage mixed-mode auth in apps.

Comment: @Alex, we didn't have any security problem and we are using it for 2 years. I didn't see any discussion about mixed auth being a security concern can you link me something?

Comment: @LeandroSoares Here you go: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/ Little after the half-way mark, where it's titled "Mixing Windows Authorization with Forms Authentication"

Comment: I'd be very hesitant to use this in production without knowing how it addresses [the "trivial attacks" on mixed-mode auth that Microsoft calls out](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/): "The ASP.NET team doesn’t support using mixed-mode authentication. ... [Y]ou’ll find blog posts on how to do this, but please note that the techniques discussed in these blog posts are discouraged. ... [T]here are trivial attacks against such a setup that can allow malicious clients to masquerade as an authenticated user."

Comment: @LeandroSoares ,  can you tell me why SaveUserIdToSession  is before WinLogoffAsync  and is  throw new ApplicationException("Id already exists in session.") instead of just overriding userID in session ?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see this in your answer, so for anyone looking on how to capture Windows Auth in your Owin pipeline, you also can add the following to your `ConfigureAuth` method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
     HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
     listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;
}
```