# Owin authentication with windows and certificate

Tags: c#, owin, windows-authentication, x509certificate

This question has been asked multiple times but none of the solutions have worked for me yet. I can't understand how they are mixing multiple authentications with windows authentication.
These links
[1]: [MVC - Mixed Auth - OWIN + Windows Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105780/mvc-mixed-auth-owin-windows-auth) 
[2]: https://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/enabling-windows-authentication-in-katana 
explains that i need to enable both Anonymous and Windows authentication to mix it up, but after enabling Anonymous authentication, my application is not asking for windows login credentials.
I tried disabling Anonymous and then added a dummy claims based authentication to authenticate every request but it was asking for windows login credentials then.
My intention is to support certificate authentication as well as windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

My methods of experimenting with authentication was wrong. Trying to setup a dummy authentication didn't work. After setting up proper environment where my api was already doing windows authentication all I had to was add token based authentication for the api inside Configuration method of OWIN

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
    new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Tenant = "tenant link",
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudiences = audienceUris
        },
   });
```

So OWIN supports multiple authentication out of box, and we just need to add an authentication method to make it work.